# Using 'continue' PHP instruction outside the loop

Tags: php

What will 'continue' instruction do if I'd use it OUTSIDE any kind of loop?
I'd assume that it should terminate the script execution.
Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried it? Seems like it would be simple enough to test out

Comment: You will get a fatal error

Comment: Why would you assume that? The manual speaks of having an effect on `looping structures`, which the script an sich isn't?

Comment: too lazy to do something like this http://codepad.org/NIsyZ3RB ? :)

Comment: What makes you think that `continue` would terminate? It will (with a fatal error); but logically, surely you'd expect continue to continue executing the code

Answer (score 5):

When it doubt, just try it...

**PHP Code**

```
continue;
```

**Result**

```
Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in C:\wamp\www\menu\circ\inctest.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

### Why not try it?

It will produce a [fatal error](https://eval.in/43043) because it's not supposed to be used outside of a loop structure.

If you want to stop script execution in a sane manner, use `die()` or `exit()` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to test:

```
function test(){
    echo "Hello";
    continue;
    echo "World";
}
test();// Fatal error:  Cannot break/continue 1 level
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will get:
`Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in __FILE__`

`continue;` is applicable in `for`, `while`, `foreach`